# angular put function 403 forbidden error not update data

Tags: angular, api, angular-httpclient

i try to update data in to api

but i throw 403 Forbidden

i don't want to send any data everything i handle in server side based on token

```
uri = 'http://localhost:3000/api/url';
token = localStorage.getItem('token');
functionName(){
      let headers = new Headers({ 'x-access-token': `${this.token}` });
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      return this.http.put(`${this.uri}`, options);
    }
```

**it throw error No token provided but i pass token**

what is the problem here ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `HttpHeaders` from `@angular/common/http` and declare your header like that:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer' + this.token
})
```

Comment: i tried my way in get methos is working fine but put and post not working

Comment: It may be about `CORS`, do you have a specific error in the console of your browser?